# How to connect ZTE MF 823 Surf Stick in virtual Linux?

Tags: opensuse, modem, lte, zte

I have an LTE Surf Stick which I would like to get working inside my virtual machine. The Stick is called "ZTE MF 823". I am running openSUSE 13.1 with NetworkManager and I was not able to find any device that matches a hard drive or a modem. Because this stick got also a hard drive for installing the Windows software. Within Windows, it is running as integrated webserver, which I can access with my browser. But this should also work under Linux, because the hardware access driver should be the same. My virtualizer is Virtual Box. I also configured the USB forwarding in Virtual Box. However, when I type `lsusb` on openSUSE I get the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I struggled with the vendor id's of the first entry of `lsusb` but I can't get it working.

Comment: "This should also work under Linux" is a false assumption if the software on the stick does use autorun to run in the Windows environment instead of providing its own, http-serving capable, processor on the stick (and all USB sticks I have seen use autorun).

Comment: so it´s impossible to run those sticks under linux?

Comment: Not necessarily impossible, but the software on the stick is most likely windows software so you either need to run that under a windows VM, or on a Windows host. Or, if the chipset is supported, by a direct driver. My Vodafone stick used to work with Ubuntu 12.04 without special software, I just had to enable the device in the network settings.

Comment: the point is, it is not listed there. It is also not listed as any usb device that is plugged in. I tink it could be, that I configured wrong the Virtual Box USB extension. But in the vm settings the usb device is enabled in the filter.

Comment: There is nothing to configure about the extension unless you want the device to automatically be allocated to the VM. You should focus on doing that by hand first, automation is not important until you get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the autorun stuff is usually managed by using usb-modeswitch.

a pretty complete overview of how to use this stick in linux can be found on the archlinux wiki at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ZTE_MF_823_(Megafon_M100-3)_4G_Modem